# SQL - create relation to echo data from two tables

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, relational-database, echo

I made some researchs but couldnt find yet the exact concept needed to achieve this:

::: EDIT ::: my initial request wasnt clear so here I try again

I have two tables,

`table_01` with four columns: `id` / `name` / `address` / `id_cat`
AND
`table_02` with two columns: `id_cat` / `category`

`id_cat` in `table_01` and `table_02` is just an INT(10), while `category` is a VARCHAR supposed to contain the exact name of the category (which is quite long). What I am trying to do is, when a query is made on `table_01`, the echo shows rows of `table_01` as result, but instead of showing `id_cat` as a number, it shows the text from `table_02` `category`.

The result shows as I am expecting it, but, if for example in `table_02`, I have a row`id_cat` = 1 , `category` = AAAAA, I would like to echo the `id_cat` from `table_01` as the `category` from `table_02`, so still for example, 002 | standon | 125 market street | AAAAA instead of what I get now, which is 002 | standon | 125 market street | 1.

I didnt create relation between both tables yet.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are after, your query for the data would just need to be something like:

```
select t1.id as id, t2.category as category from tab_01 as t1
left join tab_02 as t2 on t1.id_cat = t2.id_cat where t1.id = '5';
```

The 5 is obviously the id you are looking for in tab_01.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, do I understand well that NO relation needs to be created between both tables of this example tab_01 and tab_02 ?

Comment: Yes, you do not need to directly create a relation, although it would likely be advisable. 

You can join two tables on any columns you want, regardless of whether you have defined a specific relation between the two or not.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll take it from here so.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully clear about your question. But I think this will help you.

Right now you have created one-to-many relationship between this two tables. This means one category (`tab_02`) can have multiple `tab_01` data.

You can try this query:

```
SELECT t1.id_cat AS id_cat_number, t2.* 
FROM tab_02 t2 
INNER JOIN tab_01 t1 ON t1.id_cat = t2.id_cat 
WHERE t2.category = XXXXXXXX
```